# Return each max count of subgroup using oracle-11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
   from_id varchar2(10),
   to_id varchar2(10),
   b_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
   exp_in_date varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Sample data:

```
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140203056',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140203056',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203056',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140203057',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('2','5','20140203057',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203057',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140203058',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('2','5','20140203058',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203058',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140203059',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('2','5','20140203059',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203059',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140204059',TO_DATE('20140204', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140204059',TO_DATE('20140204', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140204059',TO_DATE('20140204', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140204059',TO_DATE('20140204', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','2','20140204059',TO_DATE('20140204', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203060',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203060',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203060',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203060',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','4','20140203061',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','3','20140203062',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','3','20140203062',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','3','20140203062',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','3','20140203062',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','3','20140203062',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203063',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203063',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203063',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203063',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203064',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203064',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203064',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
Insert into TABLE1 (FROM_ID,TO_ID,B_ID,EXP_IN_DATE) values ('5','1','20140203064',TO_DATE('20140203', 'yyyymmdd'));
```

I want to get the max of count(*) per every *'4'* b_id, each 4 b_id represents the transaction within a hour, let's say

> 20140203056 to 20140203059

e.g. expected result

```
Date-hr                     from_id to_id   count(no_record)
------------------------------------------------------------
February, 03 2014 14:00     2       5       1   
February, 03 2014 14:00     5       1       1
```

I can do simple grouping. I think I can code it in PLSQL, but the performance for that query is very important. If there is no better solution, I would like to perform for-loop and if(greater) than comparison.

Comment: I dont understand "the max of count(*) per every '4' b_id". Also I don't understand  "each 4 b_id represents the transaction within a hour"

Comment: Sorry for my poor presentation. 
It is about + get the max for next '4' 'b_id' for example the max 
from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 9 -- for b_id(1) + the max 
from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 3 -- for b_id(2) the max 
from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 1 -- for b_id(3) the max 
from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 10 -- for b_id(4)

Comment: the max transaction value (that I am looking for) sub-group of bid(1,4) is 10 (b_id = 4), 
though next value is 99 for b_id(5) the max from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 99 -- for b_id(5) 

You can think the b_id is from **yyyyMMddXXX** – where XXX is sequence of each transaction in a `hour`

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it. "the max from_id and to_id for transaction 5,2 is 9" What is transaction 5,2? 
Is it represented by the rows with `from_id=5 and to_id=2`? the `max(from_id)` of all rows of the table is `5` 
and also `max(to_id)` of all rows of the table is `5`. So what max is 9? Please edit the OP to make it clearer that is more useful then adding a lot of comments.
I think it makes sense to elaborate your example. How do you  calculate this "expected result" for the transaction from "20140203056 to 20140203059".

Comment: I am sorry that I don't know how to put linebreak in comment.

Yes. transaction 5,2 means from from_id 5 to to_id 2

The last one is just an example to explain what is the "max of count(*) per every '4 b_id'.

Comment: actual expected result per my table1 is 

(date_in_yyyymmddHH24, from_id , to_id, the_max_count)
(February, 03 2014 14:00, 5, 2, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select count(*) countx,from_id,to_id,exp_in_date
from table1
group by from_id,to_id,exp_in_date;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04383/2/0).

Comment: with results as (select b_id,
                            FROM_ID,
                            TO_ID,                        
                            count(*) as x
                     from   table1
                     group by FROM_ID, TO_ID, B_ID
                     )

Comment: select  
    to_date(to_number(substr(b_id, 1,8)), 'yyyymmdd') as mydate,
    b_id,
            FROM_ID,
            TO_ID, 
            x as "No of record"
            ,trunc(to_number(substr(b_id, 9,3)) / 4, 0) as clock,                                                
            row_number() over (
                partition by 
                 to_number(substr(b_id, 1,8)), 
                 trunc(to_number(substr(b_id, 9,3)) / 4, 0),
                 FROM_ID, TO_ID order by x desc
            ) tom
    from results